# Particle moves in square, what is the expected distance before first return to edge?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

There is a unit square with a particle moving in it. After the particle collides with an edge, the angle of reflection is random and is drawn from the uniform distribution on $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}].$

The question is to find the average distance the particle covers before it returns to the same edge next time (I guess that after a large number of collusions the starting point is not important).

To me, this sounds like a question about the stationary distribution of a Markov chain with a continuum of states. However, the problem actually is taken from a physics olympiad for high school students. It is claimed that the answer is $2\sqrt{2}$.

If it is not a mistake, there probably is an intuitive non-rigorous argument why the answer is $2\sqrt{2}$.

*Update 1: I was asked to post the original text of the problem here. It is somewhat different from what I wrote above, but I believe that this is basically the same question:*

> Problem: In a computer model, movement of a particle inside of a square is
>   simulated. Square has sides of length L, the speed of the point is V.
>   After a collusion with an edge point bounces at a random angle
>   (equiprobable from -90 to 90 degrees) with the same speed. Estimate the
>   number of collusions with one of the sides after a large period of
>   time T.
>
> Answer: $\frac{TV}{2\sqrt{2}L}$.

*Update 2: There were attempts to do a simulation (see comments below), and the results tend to be somewhat smaller than $2\sqrt{2}$.

Also, in my simulation the distribution of collision points is not uniform (points close to angles are more frequent) and distribution of distance from bounce to bounce is asymmetric and bimodal.*

Comment: Where is the starting point?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Sorry, I should have said that the question is about average distance after a large number of collusions. So I guess that the starting point is not important.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter What I think is meant here is the average distance traveled before returning to the *same* edge we started at.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter So what? You will not return to the edge in one step anyway.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Sorry, I put in an unclear way. Thank you.

Comment: Even after many bounces, it's not obvious to me that we can assume that the *location* of bounces along an edge is uniformly-distributed. In fact, I suspect it's not.

Comment: @JohnBarber I think it is not too. But I also think that this does not make the question incorrect. Average distance after a large number of collusions still can be defined.

Comment: Does the point start moving from on the perimeter or inside?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Nothing about the starting point is stated, but I guess that the initial conditions are not important for the asymptotic behavior.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the original problem please? Or if not, a verbatim quote?

Comment: @joriki I did it, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I agree that it's equivalent, but the equivalence isn't entirely trivial, and we get so many questions here that turn out to be misquoted, it seemed worthwhile to check. I think it always makes sense to provide the original problem statement because you can never be $100\%$ sure whether your (re)interpretation of it is faithful. In this case I think it is. It's a nice problem, by the way. When I find the time, I'll write a simulation to check the result and then think about it if it checks out.

Comment: @joriki Thank you so much! I tried to do a simulation too, and the result seems to be correct! At least, in my simulation the average distance the point covers from bounce to bounce is close to \sqrt{2}/2. This only makes the things more interesting.

Comment: @joriki Just a small update. I consistently get something like 2.76 as average distance of return, while 2*\sqrt{2} approximately equals 2.83. It might be some computational issue or a mistake in the code, but it also can be that the answer actually is wrong.

Comment: @Hypsoline: Interesting, thanks for the update! I'll write my own code to check, but I won't be getting around to this before tomorrow at the earliest. Note that the problem statement says "estimate", so there could be an argument why the value should be roughly but perhaps not exactly $2\sqrt2$. (A very rough but I think ultimately unjustifiable argument could be made for it to be $\pi$, which is also not too far off.)

Comment: I also find something a little smaller than $2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Well, that makes the question all the more interesting -- perhaps we can find the actual value :-)

Comment: I wonder whether the fact that it's from a physics olympiad should tell us something. Perhaps it has something to do with the [equipartition of energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) between the two degrees of freedom.

Comment: Or perhaps something related to the [mean free path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path)

Comment: @joriki There is no hurry, and thank you so much for your attention to the problem. Yes, it is from a physics olympiad, but participants were likely to be quite young (less than 17 years on average, I would say) :)

Comment: @JulianRosen Thanks a lot for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

One possible heuristic reasoning behind the answer (for the "official" problem) is the following:

1.The events of hitting each side are equiprobable (good estimate if T is big) ,so
the number of hits for a fixed side is estimated as : $\frac{(total-no-of-hits)}{4}$

2.Total traveled distance in time $T$ is $TV$

3.The longest traveled distance between two hits (between any two sides) is $\sqrt{2}L$(on the diagonal). The shortest is 0 . A rough estimate for the average distance  between two hits will be $\frac{\sqrt{2}L}{2}$ (this is the most problematic part).

4.Now we can estimate the total number of hits of any side as $\frac{2TV}{\sqrt{2}L}$

5.For a fixed side the total number of hits will be $\frac{2TV}{4\sqrt{2}L}=\frac{TV}{2\sqrt{2}L}$

Update: With these estimates the answer to the initial question is indeed $2\sqrt{2}L$ . If we introduce two random variables , X- the length of the path between two collisions  and Y - the number of sides hit until the particle returns to the side where it started will be $Z=X + YX$ . Since X and Y are independent , using the estimates from above and observing that Y follows a geometric distribution with $p=\frac{1}{3}$ we conclude that the expectation of Z is : $E[Z] = \frac{\sqrt{2}L}{2} + 3\frac{\sqrt{2}L}{2}$ = $2\sqrt{2}L$